# Disable a button in iOS when a certain image is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have an animationImages animation where my UIImage *imageView ends on the last frame of the animation.

When the last image of the animation is displayed, I would like to disable the button (buttonOne) that starts the animation, and for the animation to reset when another button (buttonTwo) is pressed. ButtonTwo puts the first image of the animation on display, so it is not displaying the last image. So basically, I'm trying to figure out a way to let the user reset the animation.

My question: how do I disable buttonOne when the last image is on display, and enable buttonOne again when the first image is on display?

Here was my first attempt:

```
- (IBAction)buttonOne:(UIButton *)sender {
if (self.imageView.image == [self.imageView.animationImages lastObject]) {[self.buttonOne     setEnabled:NO];}
else {[self.buttonOne setEnabled:YES];}
```

So far, the button just stays disabled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the code to enable the button in the button's action method, since it will be disabled at that point. I don't think there's any way to get a call back for when the animation is done, but since you set the animation duration, you can call a method to disable the button after that same time period. Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)animatePcs:(id)sender {
    self.iv.animationImages = self.pics;
    self.iv.animationDuration = 2.0;
    self.iv.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.iv startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(disableButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)disableButton {
    self.button1.enabled = NO;
    [self.button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(IBAction)reenableButton1:(id)sender { // button 2 method
    self.button1.enabled = YES;
    [self.button1 setTitleColor:self.buttonTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I set the value of buttonTextColor in viewDidLoad using [self.button1 titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal].

Comment: I just had to say [self.button1 setEnabled:NO] at the end of the the button1 method, and say [self.button1 setEnabled:Yes] at the end of the button2 method! Thanks again. Puzzle solved

Comment: @MScottWaller, that disables the button right away at the start of that animation, doesn't it (I added the title color change so I could visually tell when the button gets disabled)?

Comment: The animation is tied to pressing button1. So you hit button1, it kicks in the animation, and then it disables itself. And it becomes enabled only after pressing button2

Comment: @MScottWaller, In your question though, you said you wanted to disable the button when the last image was in the image view, which would be at the end of the animation -- if you just set the button to enabled = NO in the button's method, it will be disabled at the beginning of the animation. That's why I used the delayed call to disableButton. Anyway, if my answer helped solve your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) startanimation {

  [buttonOne.userInteractionEnabled = NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5. delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        // do your animation here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         // When your animation finished, allow users to interact with the button
        [buttonOne.userInteractionEnabled = YES];
    }];

}
```